# Is it possible to have browser open a link in already opened website?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have an application where I have tabs where each tab represent a particular sub application.

I'd like to have all links such as `site.com/*` to open in an already existing browser tab, and somehow possibly firing a JavaScript event that a new link was received/opened so that I could open it in my application instead.

So basically, I'm building a web application and I'd like to have links opening in the same application instance rather than creating multiple instances of my application.

Is this possible?

**Update:** I'm talking about if someone sends a link over Skype or email, that the links would open in my application. I'm aware of most web technologies and I can't think of any approach, that's why I left this question if someone might have an idea. Or a plugin, if not, someday we might get one and I'll add the answer my own / update question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use the [`target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) of the links to open them in their sub-application browsing context (i.e. tab, window).

There is no event that fires on opening links. You may add a click event handler to all links, executing what you need when the URL matches.

---

If you want you want your web application to open specific protocols or mime types, even that is possible with HTML5. You can use [`window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web-based_protocol_handlers) and [`window.navigator.registerContentHandler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.registerContentHandler). See the [HTML5 Draft on Custom scheme and content handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/system-state-and-capabilities.html#custom-handlers).

If a users opens a new tab/window for a link he received by email etc, you usually can't catch and prevent that. But you could use [Cross-document messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#web-messaging), e.g. `window.postMessage`, to look whether your app is already opened somewhere in the browser and then close one tab and focus the other.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry if I was misleading, I'm talking about links that open through Skype or email. :)

Comment: can you elaborate how would Cross-document messaging work exactly. I mean, `window.postMessage()` is simple, but how can I find the reference to the other `window` to talk to? It's simple if the pages are on the same document, but in different iframes. However, in my case the links from email open to a completely new tab, how does cross-document messaging work in this scenario?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I don't know any way to obtain that reference. Then I can only think of communication by changing cookies/sessionStorage, and polling for changes of them on the other side.